# Mysql need to COUNT inscription per week lasts 12 weeks

Tags: mysql, date, count, week-number

I already count inscriptions, this week.
But i need to count inscription per week last 12 weeks, and send it in an array.

My actual request is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSON
YEAR(date_inscription) = YEAR(NOW())
AND WEEK(date_inscription) = WEEK(NOW())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(date_inscription) as yweek,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM PERSON
where YEARWEEK(date_inscription) >= YEARWEEK(curdate()) - 12
group by yweek
```